# Update data table from Web form with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, webforms

I am new to PHP and there is one problem which I don't understand quite well.

I have web form and text fields. When web form loads text field get data from database.

What I am trying to do is to update databse on buton click, actually on second web form load. But data in database is not changing at all.

```
$first_name = $_POST[textfield];

session_start();
$telegramNum = $_SESSION[telegramNum]; // This is data from first page, this code is 
                                       // on third page, data was from second page

$testDataQuery="UPDATE person_response SET first_name = ".$first_name." WHERE telegram_number= " .$telegramNum;
```

Comment: how are you connecting to the db?

Comment: You're going to need to put quote marks around the text in your query, otherwise MySQL will return an error. eg: `first_name = '".$first_name."' WHERE `

Comment: I try that too. That is ok. But I get data from first page. Maybe it is problem because textfield is name of text field for first and for second page too? And I get data from first page, not from second as I wont it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in form tag. I didn't put hole part of code inside form tag.

Answer (score 1):

First i would read up on some tutorial about connection to database using php.  Then learn how to execute queries.  Also, read up a little about using mysql_real_escape_string() for data injection.

[PHP MySQL connection tutorial](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/connect-to-mysql-database.aspx)

```
$first_name = $_POST['textfield'];

session_start();
$telegramNum = $_SESSION['telegramNum'];    
$testDataQuery="UPDATE person_response SET first_name = '".$first_name."' WHERE telegram_number= '" .$telegramNum."'";
```

make sure you use single quote around the data injected in query and also around $_POST and $_SESSION vars

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to the database and send query. In your code you only assign mysql query to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't understand me. I connected with database. When page 2 is loading, text fields is updated with data from database.

But when I change some of that text field and go on another page, in that moment I want to update database with this new data. Connection and everything else is ok.

Comment: There is no error. Database is updating, but for first_name update is empty cell.

Comment: make sure you put quote around $_POST and $_SESSION and then do an echo on $first_name see if its getting value from the post

Comment: I try echo $first_name but nothing happens. I don't understand textfield is name of text field from page2. On page3 i have:

$first_name = $_POST['textfield'];
echo $first_name;

But nothing happens.

Comment: it would help if you post the codes from page2 and page3. are your forms posting at all?